# Regex from pattern until empty line or next pattern

Tags: regex

i trying extract queue info and members from text until empty line or next queue, but selected only queue info without members( I read a lot of posts but without success.Please tell right direction for solve...

I use python 3.9
last tested regex

```
^[\w\d]+.*(?!\n\n)
```

Please see example of data on regex101

https://regex101.com/r/kCrTIN/1

Comment: You should use a positive lookahead if you want to end at a specific pattern, not negative lookahead.

Comment: You need to use the `s` flag so that `.*` will match across multiple lines. And use a non-greedy quantifier so it stops at the first match of the end pattern, not the last match.

Comment: I'm not certain if I understand the question but perhaps `^(?:.+)+` is all you need. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rLP5f7/1). Note that in your regex `[\w\d]+` is the same as `\w+` as word characters include digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this.
It matches up to the next blank line or end of file.

```
(?sm)^[\w\d]+.*?(?=\r?\n\s*\r?\n|\z)
```

https://regex101.com/r/vXZI8V/1

```
 (?sm)                         # Flags: dot-all, multi-line
 ^ [\w\d]+ .*?                 # Begin of line matches 'queue'
 (?= \r?\n \s* \r?\n | \z )    # Keep matching until ahead is a blank line '\n\s*\n' typical
                               # or end of file '\z'
```